# Cómo comparar el contenido de una matriz con equals?

Tags: java, matriz

Estoy creando un programa para ver la diferencia entre una copia hecha por referencia y una copia del objeto con todos sus elementos. Al utilizar el comparador == me dice son referencias al mismo objeto lo cual es cierto pero al utilizar el equals para comparar su contenido me dice que los objetos son diferentes lo cual no es así.

```
public class Pruebas {
 public static void visualizarVector(CVector v){
    int ne = v.longitud();
    for (int i = 0; i < ne; i++) 
      System.out.print(v.valorEn(i)+" ");
      System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 double[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
 CVector vector1 = new CVector(x);
 CVector vector2 = new CVector();
 vector2.copia(vector1);

 if (vector1 == vector2) 
        System.out.println("referencias al mismo objeto");
     else
        System.out.println("referencias a objetos diferentes");
  
    if (vector1.equals(vector2))
        System.out.println("objetos iguales");
     else
        System.out.println("objetos diferentes");
    
    visualizarVector(vector1);
    visualizarVector(vector2);
    
    System.out.println("Fin de la aplicación");
 }
}

public class CVector {
 private double[] vector;
 private int nElementos;

      //Copia un CVector en otro

public CVector copia(CVector v){
      nElementos = v.nElementos;
      vector = new double[nElementos];
      //Copiar el objeto v
          for (int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) 
              vector[i] = v.vector[i];
              return this;    
  }
 }
```

Comment: Tu codigo no puede compilar, hay varios detalles, por ejemplo no se tiene un constructor de la clase CVector que reciba un parametro CVector(x)

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso, para comparar matrices deberías hacer esto:

```
if (Arrays.deepEquals(nombreMatriz1, nombreMatriz2))
{
    System.out.println("Son matrices exactamente iguales");}
    else
      {System.out.println("No Son iguales");}
```

Recuerda que con equals evaluas las referencias a objetos. deepEquals es un método recursivo y más eficaz.

Un saludo

Comment: de acuerdo al ejemplo, esto no obtendría que son iguales, te sugiero probar con el código expuesto en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes, comparar objetos con **`==`** es erróneo**, siempre que compares objetos debes usar **equals**, veamos el resultado usando tu propio código:

```
double[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
double[] y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
CVector vector1 = new CVector( x );
CVector vector2 = new CVector();
vector2.copia( vector1 );
```

Comparamos los vectores

```
System.out.println( vector1 == vector2 );  // Devuelve false
System.out.println( vector1.equals( vector2 ));  // Devuelve false
```

Comparamos los array's

```
System.out.println( x == y );  // Devuelve false
System.out.println( x.equals( y ));  // Devuelve false
```

Osea, dos objetos **siempre** devolverán false ante una comparación, esto es porque lo que se compara, es el puntero, dicho de otra forma, la dirección de memoria donde está almacenado, si quieres hacer la comparación que te te devuelva si dos objetos distintos tienen los mismos atributos, debes crear un método **compare** (o el nombre que te guste, muchos sobre-escriben **equals**, pero eso te quita la posibilidad de saber si dos objetos, en realidad son el mismo) que verifique que los atributos de los objetos sean iguales. Tanto el método **Arrays.deepEquals()** (para matrices) que mostró Jakintsu Iheslari como **Arrays.equals()** (para array's), son implementaciones de esto.

Nota: las comparaciones con **`==`** devolvieron false, pero no hay ninguna certeza que siempre devuelvan false, ya que, insisto, es un error comparar objetos con **`==`**.

**Para quedar un poco como loco, y después de decir que es un error usar **`==`**, tengo que aclarar que en el caso específico de las cadenas, cuando son creadas con un `literal` (String cadena = "Hola mundo";), y solo en ese caso, se puede usar **`==`**, ya que Java, para optimizar las aplicaciones, cuando crea una cadena, verifica si ya hay una cadena igual, en cuyo caso, usa el mismo puntero para ambas, ahora bien, no lo recomiendo, ya que la costumbre de usarlo de esa manera, puede llevarnos a emplearlo cuando no es debido.